# Keyword based Chatterbot in a Web Application

Tags: database, artificial-intelligence, bots

I'm trying to create a keyword based Chatterbot on the web. Simply look for keywords in an input and return relevant responses.

Example:

> **User(Input)**: What is your phone number?
>
> **Bot(Output)**: 555-555-5555

This would occur due to the presence of the the keyword "phone" or "number".
You could create a database of keywords:

> Output String: 555-555-5555
>
> Related Keywords (that would trigger that output):
>
> - phone
>
> - number
>
> - telephone
>
> - cell
>
> - landline
>
> - call
>
> - etc.

You could build upon that further and have it output multiple responses relating to the keywords in the input.

Example:

> User: Is there a number where I can reach you? I need to talk to you about your new address!
>
> Bot: 555-555-5555, 123 Main St.

Does anyone know where to start?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you want to know what already exists, take a look at "chatterbot" on delicious.

Maybe you could begin with AIML (ALICE).

I personally wrote such a chatterbot in C, but it was first hard-coded, and then I used a small table of stimuli-responses (Achille was the name of this software): http://francois.parmentier.free.fr/irc/achille_e.html (look at vlad-ons.c). Hum! I realize now that it is an old program, mainly hard-coded for French keywords :/

Answer (score 1):

Well, you could start with a big `if-else` statement just looking for keywords, like Eliza.

When that is not enough then you could move to pairs of ordered keywords and keyword modifiers , like NOT, MY, etc.

When that's not enough then you get in to grammars. You start with simple grammars like the ones used in the old infocom text-based games.

When that's still not enough then you enter the realm of natural language processing. You pick up Russel&Norvig's intro to AI book and then pickup a recent textbook from MIT Press on NLP and go to town on those algorithms.

Answer (score 0):

Building on what @H_I said, I strongly recommend AIML.  It is a very easy language to use: you don't even need much code using this software: http://riotsw.com/sae.html.  To work with keywords, just remember to put in the input field `* KEYWORD _` (include the spaces between the characters), so when the keyword is used, it automatically gives a set answer.  You can then upload the chatbot's AIML file to [Pandorabots](http://www.pandorabots.com/botmaster/en/home) and then load it onto your website from there!  Hope this helps.